# Difference between web service and website

Tags: web

What is the difference between web service and website ? I know the difference between Webapplication and website .  If possible please explain with example. Thank you,Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Websites vs Webservices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057649/websites-vs-webservices)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non Technical Answer:

Website: Is a site, which is designed with proper User Interface and with User Experience. It is accessed with a URL (address) and viewed only with the help of client browser.
eg. www.facebook.com opened in firefox browser

Webservice is a service in which if its consumed, will receive data from a server/database. It is accessed using a URL and other parameters (if required) and it will not have any User Interface.
eg. The data or info provided on a website would have been consumed or fetched with the help of a Webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Website is a `url(server package/program)` that is `open/known/has-access` to the end user(human user) for them to interact.

But webservice is a `url(server program)` that is(should be) accessible only by another program and the result from it, generally, is(should be) understandable only by the calling program..

A Website uses webservices & reacts based on the result from webservices at the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

Website : It is a combination of user interfaces and services or only user interface. User doesn't require any coding to consume websites. Mostly website use for static and dynamic content. It uses by end-user who is not a coder.

Webservices: It is a service and consumes by any application ( like web, native, windows etc). A consumer needs to do coding to use these services. Mostly webservice mostly use by the coder for their application.